# Deprecated: mysql_escape_string на WordPress. Шаблон использует старую версию PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, функции

Есть сайт на WordPress. Установил тему, включил отображение ошибок, и увидел:

> Deprecated: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use
>   mysql_real_escape_string() instead. in
>   /home/domanim1/public_html/wp-content/themes/site/functions.php on
>   line 60

Читал в интернете, проблема может быть вызвана тем, что хостинг переехал на более новую версию PHP, а моя тема или плагины ещё на старой. Дело в том, что тему я обновить не могу, как и плагины, и нужно как-то вручную поменять функции. Может кто сталкивался и разъяснит, что и в каком именно файле нужно изменить, чтобы исправить положение?

Пробовал менять файл `functions.php` в моей теме, нашел строку 60 и там поменял функцию mysql_escape_string на mysql_real_escape_string. В итоге начало писать такое:

```
Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is    deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO    instead in    /home/domanim1/public_html/wp-content/themes/site/functions.php on   line 60
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user    ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in    /home/domanim1/public_html/wp-content/themes/site/functions.php on   line 60
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not    be established in    /home/domanim1/public_html/wp-content/themes/site/functions.php on   line 60
```

Прикреплю саму 60-ую строчку с файла:

```
if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
```

На хостинге у меня используется PHP версия "по умолчанию" native (5.6)

Comment: он так на любую `mysql_` функцию будет ругаться, т.к. они все устарели и убраны в пхп 7. По поводу первой функции, она просто была убрана и заменена еще раньше :) Вараинтом тут будет отключить показ `E_DEPRECATED` сообщений.
Дальнейшие строки ошибки указывают на то, что невозможно подключиться к БД. Вам где-то необходимо сконфигурировать настройки подключения к БД.

Comment: @teran А правильно ли будет снизить версию PHP на хостинге?

Comment: нет, смысла в снижении версии нет. Это ведь не ошибка, а предупреждение. Их показ можно отключить, [примерно так](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2803772/1216425)

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов, нет, снижать версию неправильно. Нужно использовать современное программное обеспечение, в том числе Wordpress с его темами и расширениями. И отключать предупреждения не стоит. Их не просто так придумали.

Comment: @Visman как же теперь быть?

Comment: @Visman кто-то оставляет на продакшене показ ошибок и предупреждений? серьезно?

Comment: @teran, то есть вы забиваете все логи сервера предупреждениями,а не решаете причину их появления? Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов, обновляйте устаревшее на то что работает на современном программном обеспечении  Сейчас уже все должно функционировать на PHP 7.

Comment: @Visman не всегда можно легко и быстро решить проблему использования deprecated-фукнций, и показа сообщений.  И не обязательно вообще забивать ими лог, отключите их протоколирование. Эти сообщения информируют, что в дальнейших версиях что-то поддерживаться не будет,а не то, что надо срочно бежать и исправлять весь код для исключения deprecated-функций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновлять ничего не надо, в вашей же ошибке всё чётко написано где проблема, вам надо открыть файл `functions.php` в вашей теме, найти строку 60 и там поменять функцию `mysql_escape_string` на `mysql_real_escape_string`

> Обновлено

Также стоит помнить что начиная с версии `PHP 5.5.0` методы `MYSQL` уже устарели, а в версии `PHP 7.0.0` методы `MYSQL` удаленны, вам необходимо уже использовать `MYSQLi`  т.е для экранирования ипользуется фукция `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Посмотрите, я дополнил свой вопрос. Я уже пробовал это делать

Comment: я обновил ответ, попробуйте данный вариант, хотя нормальная работоспособность зависит от многих факторов, например какая версия Wordpress ?

Comment: Выдаёт теперь: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in /home/domanim1/public_html/wp-content/themes/workscout/functions.php on line 60

Comment: у вас там проблема с кавычками, проверьте код

Comment: Прошу прощения. Теперь вот такое: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/domanim1/public_html/wp-content/themes/workscout/functions.php on line 60 и перестал ajax фильтр работать на странице

Comment: я бы посоветовал прочитать документацию http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php, так будет лучше для вас

Comment: главное чтобы `$link` теперь был от `mysqli` а не `mysql` :D

Comment: Да я сам не разберусь )

Comment: вам необходимо использовать подключения к базе уже методом MYSQLi, в двух словах трудно будет вам описать что должны сделать, и особенно на wordpress, возможно вам поможет данный плагин 
https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-db-driver/faq/
но точно не могу сказать )) + объязательно сделайте бекап файлов и базы перед глобальными изменениями